# visualize different binary matrices with different in R

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, visualize

Assume I have two binary matrices in R program.

```
A = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
B = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Here, `A` and `B` are adjacency matrices for two different social networks. How can I visualize the above two matrices in the same plot but with different colors?

The plot will be something like this: The x-axis and y-axis have three users.
and the scatter point of `A` and `B` will be plotted with different colors.

Comment: How do you want to visualize one of the matrix? We can help you add second one in different color. Please share what have you done till now.

Comment: I am new to R and I don't know how to visualize the matrices in R. `A` is one network and `B` is another social network. I want to distinguish them.

Comment: So if you want a scatterplot, what would be the x and y coordinates from these matrices?

Comment: X and Y all represent the users since A and B are user-user social network

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using `igraph`.  There are lots of layout options, so you'll probably want to read the various help pages for `igraph`, but hopefully this will get you started.

```
library(igraph)
A = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
B = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)

#define a layout so that both sets of nodes overlap
lay <- layout_in_circle(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(A))

plot(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(A),layout=lay,edge.color="blue")
plot(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(B),layout=lay,edge.color="red",add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for the plot. However, I want to plot scatter plot for A and B. I update my question.